# Far Cry: Primal communicating with servers when starting up?

Tags: hosting, networking, far-cry-primal

Why does *Far Cry: Primal* communicate with Ubisoft servers when you start the game.  The only thing that it claims to be doing is getting game configuration information, which the game should be able to easily store on the system.  Is this some cloud-based configuration thing that can be used across multiple games or what?

This seems quite unnecessary, and would put undue strain on Ubisoft's servers for something which could be so trivially stored on the game system, in addition to the potentially inconvenient fact that playing the game seems to require an internet connection.

Comment: I've seen other Ubisoft games do this. I believe it is due to cross-series add-ons (Assassin's Creed had unlockable outfits depending on other games completed in the series). It's a way to keep it up-to-date, and yes, I believe it is cloud based. However it could also be for game updates, which a lot of games do

Comment: I'm a bit more cynical than Ben. I would argue it's just a form of DRM and Ubisoft being "big brother" and monitoring connections. Cross-series add-ons and updates can both be handled outside of the game. This way, Ubisoft maintains ultimate control over who can play the game and when.

Comment: @DaniloV, like they should, given that they own the rights to the game and playing it. 

On the topic of the question, it could be any number of reasons, but i would guess it is for syncing your saves and DRM.